# Correcting Hindi (Unicode) rendering in Android

Tags: android, unicode, hindi

I successfully added a custom typeface (DroidSansFallBack.ttf) to show Hindi characters instead of Blocks on Pre ICS . All is working well on 4.1+ in any case.

But the rendering order is wrong on Froyo and Gingerbread. 
I understand it is not resolved http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4153

What are the possible workarounds to correct the rendering? (I don't want to use images )

EDIT:
Example,

**दिन** string from values-hi renders as **दनि**

**नक्षत्र** renders as **नक् ष त र**

(On 4.1+ everything renders correctly)

Comment: Try with some other Hindi font, u can try something from http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Devanagari.html

Comment: @the100rabh I doubt the font is the problem since it works for 4.1+

Comment: Can you show how to display the strings? Is it in code, xml (values-hi)?..

Comment: @the100rabh I have tried some other fonts Mangal.ttf Akshar.ttf and others. But the problem is not in the font it is a known issue of glyp h rendering as explained in the issue on code.google.com. What I want to know is a feasible technical workaround for pre ics devices.

Comment: @shkschneider I have added sample strings. But the problem is well known and documented as explained on google code issue. I would want some thing that would let me render these correctly (for a webview atleast)

Comment: @Alok did u find the solution

Comment: @BCT Unfortunately I couldnt find a solution or a workaround for this. I had to disable the option of Hindi for Pre ICS Devices.

Comment: @Alok: Hi,I would like to support hindi language in my application.can you guide me where to start from?

Comment: @MehulJoisar I added Unicode Hindi only for devices with Android version 4.0 or later. For previous versions I had to disable the use of Hindi.

Comment: @Alok: That is fine,but I am novice for the whole process of supporting hindi font in application.suppose I have softcopy of hindi story in word/pdf format.then `how to get its unicode` and how to display it in application without pdf reader or quick office softwares?

Comment: @MehulJoisar The way I handled it in my app Hindu Calendar is to give an option to change the locale of the app. So once it i schanged to "hi" (hindi) it takes the resources from folder values-hi. In the xml files there the hindi text is written corresponding to the English ones.

Comment: @Alok: But how did you get hindi texts ? i.e. if u have ebook of storybook in hindi then how will u display that in your application ?

Comment: @MehulJoisar Displaying an ebook(in pdf) is a task for a pdf renderer. What I am talking about is displaying text in TextField, or WebViews. I dont know how pdf can be shown inside an app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could not find a simple work around for fixing the rendering everywhere. So finally I had to limit the Hindi language feature to devices having android version 4.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I have a alternative solution for your problem but not exact... 
use font....

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Hindi-SARAL1.TTF");
```

for नक्षत्र use .......

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

tv.setText("n95"); 

tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

and for दिन........ unicode value continues no gap.. i have given a space between &# and 2367;

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("&# 2367;&# 2342;&# 2344;"));

 tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

---

Comment: Yes I considered this solution. But it will only be a solution for adding Hindi. What I needed was to implement a Android Resource based solution to implement multiple Indian languages (like Tamil) in unicode.