# Rendering HIndi font on Android 2.3 and lower

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, hindi

I am developing an android App in Hindi but find that few characters are misspelled and broken in Hindi the issue is in http://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=1008 but no solution there दिप is rendered as दपि
letters in hindi font above are formed as द + ि + प which should display as दिप but It render as दपि
The same question was put earlier but not resolved so I had to repost it again
[Correcting Hindi (Unicode) rendering in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569698/correcting-hindi-unicode-rendering-in-android)

Comment: **Have A Look this Post **
            
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608520/how-to-get-hindi-fonts-in-android/18184888#18184888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution this is very simple just import the font in my case I am developing web app

> @font-face {  font-family: hindi;  src: url('fonts/k010.TTF'); } 
>   body,h1,h2{ font-family:hindi; }

then type text in your a text editor or MS-word using Kruti devi10 font after You finished change the font to  Arial and paste the text in your web App and it will render perfectly

Comment: hi,I want to render hindi text in my android application's `TextView` ,I have unicode data and I have tried with `mangalb.ttf` but it is not rendering perfectly.it is having same issue as u have pointed in your question.can u guide me to solve it?

Comment: @MehulJoisar I was developing web App mehul and find the solution just using the font family kurti-devi and using css font-family for the content. I didn't try that in native but hope It should work on that too

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately it's not working on native.anyways,thanks for the response !!

Comment: @MehulJoisar we can work together in next few days to fix this , me too have to covert my HTML webapp to Native app

Comment: @MehulJoisar for native its very simple check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview. I did this in my application with -->  String otfName = "fonts/krutidevi.ttf";Typeface font = ypeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), otfName);textView.setTypeface(font);

Comment: but it doesn't give proper output.I am facing the misspelled and broken characters as you have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Unicode ...

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewmyView);

final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Hindi-SARAL1.TTF");

tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("&# 2367;&# 2342;&# 2346;"));

tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

unicode value continues no gap.....

and you can also convert world to unicode via this site...http://mylanguages.org/converter.php but in case of इ  1st use unicode of इ  then alphabets Unicode...b/c till android version 4.0 Hindi Unicode not supported proper..