# How to get Hindi fonts in Android..?

Tags: android, fonts, hindi

I'm new to Android field . I have followed the procedure of getting Hindi fonts on emulator but still Hindi characters are appearing in square boxes. Please help me how to proceed. I m using android 2.2 ,juno version. Any help regarding above problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the emulator's locale and language?  What about setting the system font to the uploaded font?

Comment: Android doesn't support Hindi fonts by default, so changing locale and language don't help. Manoj's suggestion to add it as a font might work, though it will probably still have problems loading it from WebView if you choose to do so.

Comment: there is no option of hindi fonts in locale i have copied the hindi fonts in asset folder..how can i add hindi fonts in locale n language as hindi..?

Comment: where u want to use hindi fonts.. whether in program or in device

Answer (score 4):

Set The Hindi Font on TextView in Android

```
 TextView t = new TextView(this);
 Typeface Hindi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mangle.ttf");
 t.setTypeface(Hindi);
 t.setText("Naveen Tamrakar");
```

Answer (score 1):

Android does not yet fully support Hindi (droid fonts):

Read this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1618).

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in assets as "fonts".
Place your .ttf file of font in that.

then try the code as :

```
Typeface fontHindi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(fontHindi);
```

It works for me. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You can download hindi fonts from http://hindi-fonts.com and copy it in /system/font directory of your phone. The font will be installed.

Comment: this site provides exe files, not ttf fonts.

Answer (score 0):

First of all download hindi font, d the OTF/TTF file you get, save that in asset folder, **eclipse** has already the folder, if you are using **android studio**, then make a new folder in `project/app/src/main`.

Then in java file, suppose you have to apply your font on `TextView t1`, use the code..

```
Typeface mytypeface= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font-file_name.TTF");
t1.setTypeface(mytypeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can use **Hindi font in Android**.

Step 1:  Add All Hindi text in res --> values --> string.xml file

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">गन्ने से समृद्धि</string>
<string name="ganne_ki_kheti">गन्ने  की  खेती</string>
<string name="sampark">संपर्क</string>
```

Step 2: In layout xml file add text tag as android:text="@string/your_text".
        For Example see below.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/ganne_ki_kheti"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```