# Reading Arabic text file from raw folder in android

Tags: android, arabic

I need to read Arabic text stored into file in raw folder and display the text into textview.
When i try to do it i have got a strange text.

Comment: May Use Full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608520/how-to-get-hindi-fonts-in-android/18184888#18184888

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use a external font and add it to assest folder.

```
TextView txtView;
Typeface arabicFont;

txtView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.arabicTextDisplayTextView);
arabicFont =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"arabic_fonttf");
txtView.setTypeface(arabicFont);     
txtView.setTextSize(20);

InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.arabic_text); 
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
int myInt=0;

try{
    ByteArrayBuffer myByteArray = new ByteArrayBuffer(100); 
    while((myInt = bis.read())!=-1)
    {
        if(myInt == 10) break;
        myByteArray.append((byte)myInt);
    }

    String arabicLine = new String(myByteArray.toByteArray(), 0, myByteArray.length(), "UTF-8");
    txtView.setText(arabicLine);
```