# Check if device supports Unicode?

Tags: java, android, unicode

I am trying to add `localization` in my **android app**. The device which doesn't support `Unicode` shows boxes only. Is there any way to check whether the device **supports Unicode** or not?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

I am localizing my app to support **Nepali language** as well.
If I run this on device with **4.4.2** it shows all the characters but when i run this on **2.3** it shows boxes.

Some of unicode characters are `० १ २ ३ ४ ५ ६ ७ ८ ९ क ख` etc.

Note: these are Devanagari script, used for Hindi and other related languages.

Comment: All Android devices *support* Unicode (some odd native issues aside), however the font (and where such Unicode is rendered) may not have said glyphs.. which are suitably replaced with the "boxes". So, 1) *where* is the Unicode text being rendered and 2) *which* Unicode characters are being used?

Comment: thanks for the reply ... is there any way to check whether it supports the unicode character that's being used in the app?

Comment: @MichaelShrestha : Your question is ambiguous. As mentioned, *ALL* Android devices "support" Unicode as the `String` class is backed by an array of characters in UTF-16 format. Whether or not a device has the relevant character set able to display characters you need is another question. There are various other complications depending on how you are creating or obtain strings of text and how they're encoded. Look at the Android `Locale` class http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html and you'll see a method `getAvailableLocales()` maybe that's what you need.

Comment: All devices use the same common fonts. All fonts support Unicode. Not all glyphs are included in the standard fonts. The only way to forcibly provide the missing glyphs is to change the font. This is easily done and free TTF fonts can be downloaded and used. There are also specialized "icon fonts".

Comment: If you want help please edit the question to specify which exact characters are appearing as boxes. All Android phones support Unicode, no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

These characters appear to be in Devanagari script. For example

```
'क' is Unicode Character 'DEVANAGARI LETTER KA' (U+0915)
```

Older versions of Android have limited support for this script, but it is built in which means you should simply be able to check the version of Android to find out whether they are supported.

See 
[How to get Hindi fonts in Android..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608520/how-to-get-hindi-fonts-in-android)
https://www.facebook.com/DevanagariAndroid
http://www.androidos.in/2010/12/android-2-3-brings-more-languages-support-incl-hindi/

Answer (score 0):

Android supports unicode by default. However not all unicode characters are defined in any one installed font.

Three fonts are installed on every android phone:  normal (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif), and monospace (Droid Sans Mono).

On top of that you app can include it's own TrueType fonts which allow you add any characters you would like.

Comment: thanks for the response.. but that's not what i am looking for.. I don't want to install any fonts... just want to check whether it's supported or not.

Comment: I am telling you that every droid phone has the same fonts installed and so they have the same unicode support. You can view every character supported by using a ttf editor. The font files are in /system/fonts

Comment: No. Other applications can have other fonts, but system wide only a rooted phone could have more fonts.

Comment: Or if you alter your /system/fonts some other way I suppose