# Hindi Font on android Motorola droidx

Tags: android, motorola, hindi

I am developing an app in Hindi font.

My app showing perfect Hindi results on **Galaxy S3** (OS 4.1.1) and **Galaxy S** (OS 2.3.3) but there is some issue with **Droidx** (OS 2.3.3)

There i found some character mistakes.

What are the reasons??

How i can show the perfect Hindi result on the Droid x as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u try by adding the font ttf file in assest folder ?

Comment: yes this is what i am doing right now.

Comment: same issue on HTC as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devnagari(Hindi/Marathi) fonts are not supported in most of the older devices(< 4.0) for devices manufactured by Motorola, HTC. You can replace the default font after rooting the device.

Comment: can we do rooting by application programming ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454596/rendering-hindi-font-on-android-2-3-and-lower/15460430#15460430